# How install the Amazon ECS Container Agent in Debian? (ecs-init)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, docker, debian, amazon-ecs

I have a ec2 instance with Debian jessie and when I'm doing this command :

```
apt-get install ecs-init
```

I receive a error package not found..

So I need add new depo on my Debian ?

It did not work for me : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-agent-install.html

thx.

[amazon-ecs-init](https://github.com/aws/amazon-ecs-init)

Answer (score 5):

`ecs-init` is a RPM package shipped with Amazon Linux by default, and I think could be easily ported to other RPM-powered Linux distributions, such as RedHat Linux, CentOS, Fedora, and etc. To run Amazon ECS container agent on non-RPM-powered systems, you can instead run a docker container of [`amazon/amazon-ecs-agent`](https://hub.docker.com/r/amazon/amazon-ecs-agent/). Refer to the section *To install the Amazon ECS container agent on a non-Amazon Linux EC2 instance* from the lower part of [Installing the Amazon ECS Container Agent](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-agent-install.html) for more details

Below is an example, copy-and-paste from [Installing the Amazon ECS Container Agent](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-agent-install.html), of how to run a amazon-ecs-agent instance

```
ubuntu:~$ sudo docker run --name ecs-agent \
--detach=true \
--restart=on-failure:10 \
--volume=/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
--volume=/var/log/ecs/:/log \
--volume=/var/lib/ecs/data:/data \
--volume=/sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro \
--volume=/var/run/docker/execdriver/native:/var/lib/docker/execdriver/native:ro \
--publish=127.0.0.1:51678:51678 \
--env=ECS_LOGFILE=/log/ecs-agent.log \
--env=ECS_LOGLEVEL=info \
--env=ECS_DATADIR=/data \
--env=ECS_CLUSTER=cluster_name \
amazon/amazon-ecs-agent:latest
```